# How/Where To Set a Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm working on passing a variable that exists within a function via delegation. For the most part, everything seems to work. The only thing I cannot figure out is how to set the delegate, e.g. it should be something like `"foo".delegate = self`

Normally this would be simple, but since I am working with a variable that is in a function instead of a class, I have no idea what `foo` would be (please excuse the lingo, I needed a placeholder)

For your reference

Here is the protocol:

```
protocol TagToIndexDelegate {
func finishPassing (dictionary:Dictionary<Int,Int>)
}
```

Here is the function I am trying to send the variable from:

```
extension MyCell: YSSegmentedControlDelegate {

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {
    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index

    delegate?.finishPassing(dictionary: tagToIndex)
}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, didPressItemAt index: Int) {

}}
```

Where `delegate` is of type `TagToIndexDelegate`, and the variable `tagToIndex` which exists within `willPressItemAt` is the data I am passing.

And finally, the class I am trying to implement `TagToIndexDelegate`

```
class AnswerViewController: UIViewController, TagToIndexDelegate {

func finishPassing (dictionary: Dictionary <Int, Int>)
{

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
}
```

I'm pretty new to using delegates, so any help or critiques are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's going on here.  If the delegate is part of `MyCell`, then wouldn't it be set up by whoever initializes the `MyCell`?  Where does that occur?

Comment: have you tried inside viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `AnswerViewController` is the view controller which contains the table view and cells referenced in the question, it is likely also the table view datasource.

Your `UITableViewDataSource` implementation, in which you're creating `MyCell` instances, probably looks something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "my_cell_reuse_id") as! MyCell
    return aCell
}
```

What you have to do is simply set the delegate to `self`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "my_cell_reuse_id") as! MyCell
    aCell.delegate = self
    return aCell
}
```

Note that I'm assuming that `delegate` is a property of `MyCell`:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: TagToIndexDelegate?
}
```

Comment: MyCell is actually the custom class that contains all of the data for making the cells. If you need, I can post the code in its entirety. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure, go ahead.